# Printing function values while returning with main loop

Tags: python, list

I am writing a code for student record... This is what i've tried

```
def std1():
    stud=input('Enter Student name')
    crs=[]
    crst=int(input('How many courses you want to enter'))

    for i in range(crst):
        EnterCourse = input('Course')
        crs.append(str(EnterCourse))
    stdrec1=(stud,crs)


    return main()

def std2():
    stud=input('Enter Student name')
    crs=[]
    crst=int(input('How many courses you want to enter'))

    for i in range(crst):
        EnterCourse = input('Course')
        crs.append(str(EnterCourse))
    stdrec2=(stud,crs)

def main():

    print("""
    Welcome to the Student Database
    [1] = Enter Student Record
    [2] = Enter Second Student Record
    [3] = Enter Third Student Record
    [4] = Print the record

    """)

    action = input('What Would you like to do today? (Enter number to Continue) ')

    if action == '1':
        std1()
    elif action == '2':
        print('2')
    elif action == '3':
        print('3')
    elif action == '4':
        print(#all the list together)

    else:
        print('Error! Wrong Menu Selected | Calling the FBI now')
```

How can i make all the tuples print together when the option 4 is selected which are currently inside their own function and in case user hasn't work on a 2nd option for example. it will print like this

First student --- Name , [courses]
2nd student ----- You haven\t't entered anything
Do you want to enter Y or N

Y will return that function and N will stop the function.

and after input data in each option how will it return the main function again so user can re-select the options

Comment: I think what you need is a student *Class*, not separate functions.  You've built much of the infrastructure on your own, already.  At the very least, you need a list or dict of student records.

Comment: Why are you using two different functions (`std1` and `std2`) for the same thing? You should take a look at classes. They will be very helpful for your problem.

Comment: std 1 is for 1st student and std2 is for second.... Actually i have to do it through functions.

Comment: A function is not for storing Information. Return the tuple with the Information and put the action chooser in a loop with an additional option to end the program.
But a student class would be a better solution.